# Excel spreadsheet with font in different cells to be different colors

Tags: microsoft-excel

I recently upgraded to Office 365.  An Excel spreadsheet that I have used for years has font in different cells in Bold and different colors.  I am unable to change the font color when selecting either the cell or the actual words.  Normally when I highlight and click on Font/Color and select say purple, it would change and also on the ribbon it would change to purple until the next time I use it.  Now it always stays Red and I cannot change colors.

Answer (score 0):

Check the conditional formatting options in the spreadsheet. If you have conditional formatting set, it won't allow you to change the cell color if the data itself has not changed.